# Update panel automatically clears textboxes

Tags: asp.net, ajax, vb.net

I'm trying to combine an event of automatic printing of messages in case the passwords will not match. For that purpose I'm using an Update panel.

The Error message prints perfectly My problem is that both text-boxes automatically created after it. even thought I don't specify it in the code. I can't understand what have I done wrong.

This is the code for front end:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="NonPass1" runat="server" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox>
 <asp:TextBox ID="NonPass2" runat="server" TextMode="Password" autopostback="True"></asp:TextBox>
                     <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel6" runat="server">
                     <ContentTemplate>
                     <asp:Panel ID="Panel6" runat="server">
                     <asp:Label ID="Label1"  class="errorMess" runat="server" Text="The Passwords do not match!!!"></asp:Label>
                     </asp:Panel>
                     </ContentTemplate>
                     <Triggers>
                     <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="NonPass2" EventName="TextChanged" />
                     </Triggers>
                     </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

this is the back end code(I'm using VB):

```
Protected Sub NonPass2_TextChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles NonPass2.TextChanged
    If NonPass1.Text <> NonPass2.Text Then
        Panel3.Visible = False
        Panel6.Visible = True
    Else
        Panel3.Visible = False
        Panel6.Visible = False
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: do you know password field will not persist value after form postback? If you want compare both password then go by javascript and validate it..

Comment: I'm validating it in VB

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can use javascript functions.

```
<script>
    var t1 = false; // textbox1 onfocus triggered = true;
    var t2 = false; // textbox2 onfocus triggered = true;
    function clearTBox() {
        if (t1 && t2) {
            if (document.getElementById("textbox1Name").value != document.getElementById("textbox1Name2").value) {
                alert("Insert your code here");
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: where the alert message will be printed? I had specifically told it should not be printed in the separate window but below the textboxes

Answer (score 0):

what do you mean :
My problem is that both text-boxes automatically created after it

please, make your question more clearance

---

Try not to use updatepanel,

try this

`<asp:TextBox ID="NonPass1" runat="server" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox>
 <asp:TextBox ID="NonPass2" runat="server" TextMode="Password" autopostback="True"></asp:TextBox>
<div id="Div_Error" runat="server" visible="false" style="width:100%">

                     <asp:Label ID="Label1"  class="errorMess" runat="server" Text="The Passwords do not match!!!"></asp:Label>`

and use this in the code behind:

`Protected Sub NonPass2_TextChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles NonPass2.TextChanged
    If NonPass1.Text <> NonPass2.Text Then
       Div_Error.visible=true;
    Else
        Div_Error.visible=false;
    End If
End Sub`

Comment: This is not an answer, if you can't comment don't use 'post answer' instead of a comment.

Comment: what I mean is that Ater the error message is printed both boxes for the passwords are cleared. I don't know why and this is what i'm trying to avoid

Comment: if i click outside of the text boxes for password and for repeat password their content is gone regardless if the passwords match or not.

Comment: Thanks Alla Salah But if I don't use Update panel the page will reload and i want to output error message dynamically without reloading.

Comment: would you put the full functionality in the page??and i will make it as you like..

Answer (score 0):

Heres what i use in c# for this, maybe you can inherit the technique

```
    private void ClearTextBoxes()
    {
        Action<Control.ControlCollection> func = null;

        func = (controls) =>
        {
            foreach (Control control in controls)
                if (control is TextBox)
                    (control as TextBox).Clear();
                else
                    func(control.Controls);
        };

        func(Controls);
    }
```

then call cleartextboxes();

Hope that helped :)

Comment: Thanks. But this is what I'm trying to avoid. The text boxes are being cleared automatically. But I want to retain the content.

Comment: I can't understand why are they being cleared. I don't specify it in my code anyhow

Answer (score 0):

The only logical reason for the behavior as you described is perhaps, you put the above password boxes inside another `UpdatePanel`.

Therefore, the password boxes will be reloaded on postbacks (textchanged event), and TextBox of type Password do not retain its value after postbacks for security reason.

Though, if security is not a concern for you, there is a workaround to 'avoid' the password textboxes from being cleared on postbacks, by reassigning their values every time postbacks occur. Just include the following codes in the page Load event.

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    NonPass1.Attributes.Add("value", NonPass1.Text)
    NonPass2.Attributes.Add("value", NonPass2.Text)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

*this is a simple example:*

```
<table class="mytable" cellspacing="0" style="width: 100%">
<tr>
<td> 
<asp:TextBox ID="Txt_Pass" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>
</td>
<td>
<asp:TextBox ID="Txt_Re_Pass" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>
</td>

<td width="66%" align="left"> 
<asp:Button ID="Btn_Filter" runat="server" Text=""  Height="22px" />

</td>

</tr>
</table>

<br />

<div  id="Div_Error" runat="server" visible="false" style="width:100%">
<asp:Label ID="lbl_Error" runat="server" class="msg">
</asp:Label>

</div>
```

and in the code behind , use this:

```
Protected Sub Btn_Filter_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Btn_Filter.Click

If Trim(Txt_Re_Pass.Text) <> "" Then
Div_Error.Visible = False
if Txt_Pass.Text <> Txt_Re_Pass.Text then
Div_Error.Visible = True
lbl_Error.text="The Passwords do not match!!!""
else
Div_Error.Visible = False
End if
Else
Div_Error.Visible = True
lbl_Error.text="Please re enter your password"
End If

End Sub
```